# PHP Insert Data from SELECT Query and Variable

Tags: php, oracle

I'm using PHP Oracle. Is it possible to insert data from `SELECT` query and variable?

```
$dataValue = "U0001";

$qInsert = oci_parse($c1, "
    INSERT INTO TBLDATA(DATAID, DATAVALUE)
    SELECT DATAID_FK FROM TBLACCESSDATA
");
oci_execute($qInsert);
```

So I want DATAID will be insert by SELECT query and DATAVALUE from `$datavalue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$qInsert = oci_parse($c1, "
    INSERT INTO TBLDATA(DATAID, DATAVALUE)
    SELECT DATAID_FK,$datavalue FROM TBLACCESSDATA
");
```

A better way is to use prepared statements:

```
$qInsert = oci_parse($c1, "
    INSERT INTO TBLDATA(DATAID, DATAVALUE)
    SELECT DATAID_FK,:datavalue FROM TBLACCESSDATA
");
oci_bind_by_name($qInsert, ':datavalue', $datavalue, -1);
```

It is better, because it prevents SQL-injection.

Comment: Working perfect. Thanks Jens